# An untypical config with JSON using Spring Boot Rest API

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am sending the following JSON to the backend (with header content-type json):

```
{
    "userid": 1,
    "gamedata": {
        "completedMissions": 1,
        "points": 40
    }
}
```

At backend, my controller is implemented in the following way:

```
@RestController
public class PlayerGameDataController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json", produces="application/json", value = "/player/syncgamedata")
    @ResponseBody public ResponseEntity<PlayerGameData> syncUser(@RequestBody HashMap map) {
        String data = map.get("gamedata").toString();
        ...
    }

}
```

However the value of gamedata is being replaced by:

```
completedMissions=1
points=40
```

I'd like to know why this is happening...
How can I solve this?

Comment: I cannot see what the problem is. You post that there was 1 completed mission with 40 points, and that is what gets printed...

Comment: My problem is that Spring replaced : by = and removed "

Comment: gamedata is a map that contains 2 entries. completedMissions and points. When you call toString on that map it gets converted to a string with "=". Try printing map.get("gamedata").get("completedMissions") and see if you get the expected value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `map.get("gamedata")` seems to return another `Map` with has the `String` representation you are given.

```
{completedMissions=1,points=40}
```

If you expect a `Map`, do not invoke `toString()` on the map value, cast* to a `Map` and go it further.

> My problem is that Spring replaced `:` by `=` and removed `"`.

Yes, but it's the expected behavior. A `Spring` deserialiser can parse a JSON request like a `Map<String, Map<String, ...>>` and it is allowed to do so, cause you did not specify what you want by `HashMap` which simply is `HashMap<Object, Object>`.

**There are two options here:**

1. Trying to pass a `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>` which clearly tells Spring what the structure actually is.
2. Presenting it as a `Map<String, JsonNode>` since the `JsonNode#toString` returns an unformatted JSON representation.

---

*It's not OK you are using a raw type of the `HashMap` as a method parameter. Consider working with the generic superclass `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>` or providing your own class with a similar structure.

Comment: If I print String data = map.get("gamedata"); it will be the same. Are you saying to put the value of map in another map instead of String?

Comment: @Rafael, because when you are printing an object, the `toString()` is called implicitly on it.

Comment: I haven't a mapped class for this structure because I need to get this json and save in the database. This structure is so generic.

Comment: Ok, @AndrewTobilko
I'm gonna try and I tell you if it worked.

Comment: @Rafael, I updated 2 available options and tested them as well, the second one with `map.get("gamedata").toString()` returns your desired result `{"completedMissions":1,"points":40}`